# How to build my own version of Material UI with custom stylings and add to my own github in order to reuse in all my applications

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, themes

I'm posting this question here to get your opinion about the best suitable solution since this question can answer in different ways.

I'm using MUI for my react web development projects. All of my projects are based on MUI. There are not much of a difference between MUI styling and my UI design. As an example, MUI button and my UI design buttons are pretty much same. Only difference is the color and the border radius.

What I am currently doing is doing the theming manually. When ever I want to create a new project based on my colors and styles, I'm copying the theme file from one of my old projects to the new project. What I want is create my own custom library based on MUI which will coping theme file is no longer required. So I can upload this to github and add to my package.json of the new project.

**In simple term, I'm looking for a way when I install MUI to a new project, where I can override the existing theme without copying and pasting theme file. Maybe hosting this file in a github repo and installing as a package and when the package is installed, MUI use that specific customized theme as the default one instead of their own theme.**

Highly appreciate your response.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since MUI is an open-source MIT License package, you can fork the repo and change the theming there.

How you'd go about doing this, is up to you, but give the documentation a read and it might give you some ideas.

My personal way of doing this would be creating a repo that implements MUI and create a package that contains my own customized components that expect variables to define their data/onChange or other logic stuff. This is a lot of work though, so up to you.

Example of a component that has been manually styled that expects variables:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Box, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';

import { stylesInputProps, sxTypographyOptions } from './styles';

export default function FilterInput({ flexSize, inputTitle, inputValue, inputOnChange }) {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ flex: flexSize }}>
            <Typography sx={sxTypographyOptions}>{inputTitle}</Typography>
            <TextField
                id={inputValue}
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={inputOnChange}
                inputProps={stylesInputProps}
                inputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
                fullWidth
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

You can just, instead of doing what I did, use the theming tools of MUI.

With this you can have a package that is named '@mui-namehere' which has these custom components that are just basically importing the original MUI components and applying your pre-defined styles.

Again, its very time consuming at the start, but can save a lot of time later on. This is specially helpful for big companies with many projects and many front end developers that like to use MUI, but have been finding it tiresome to always manually style the components to maintain company's identity while not deviating from other projects. Its a way to maintain a pattern and reduce workload.

**Repo Link:** https://github.com/mui/material-ui

**Documentation Link:** https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/